# How to configure an OpenVPN connection with network manager?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I am trying to use network manager to add an OpenVPN connection, but the option isn't there. I have installed both the [openvpn [image: Install openvpn]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openvpn) and [network-manager-openvpn [image: Install network-manager-openvpn]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/network-manager-openvpn) packages:

[image]

What am I missing? The computer is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: did you reboot?

Comment: @MarkYisri yes.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that was it. If you post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Good news.  That means this is a duplicate of my answer linked above though, so if you like, please upvote that one, and I'll vote to close this as a dupe.